# Realm-Swift: Thousands of objects in memory

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My app is using to much RAM (165MB) for a small app. So I opened memory debugger and saw

[image]

Do I have to wonder about this?

Here is my Realm object

```
class ZoneLevelChild: PersistentObject{

    @objc dynamic var childId: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    var children = List<ZoneLevelChild>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "childId"
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        childId <- map["ZoneId"]
        name <- map["Name"]
        children <- (map["Children"], ArrayTransform<ZoneLevelChild>())
    } 
}
```

PersistentObject is

```
class PersistentObject: Object, Mappable {

    override var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            logger.error("Error: PersistentObject hashValue needs to be overriden!")
            return 0
        }
    }

    required init(map: Map) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: schema, schema: schema)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {}

}
```

It enables mapping with Alamofire and ObjectMapper and persistence in Realm.

Here are deeper insights into Realm (37627)
[image]

Comment: Do you have any examples for what's in the 32627 references?

Comment: I added a picture of it. Hope it helps